# Simulate a click (in node) for vanilla JS using mocha and chai?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, jsdom

I'm using Mocha and Chai for unit testing.

Now I want to simulate a click event on an element. In a regular dom environment you could use [.click() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) As shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/Spindle/jwyx6L84/

However, since the tests I'm running in a Node environment, this isn't working obviously.

The following is the test scenario example:

```
import { describe } from 'mocha';

const expect = require('chai').expect;
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

describe('example...', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    const { window } = new JSDOM(`
      <!doctype html><html>
          <button class="trigger" onclick="this.classList.add('test-class')">
          </button>
        </html>`, { runScripts: "dangerously" });
        // setting it to dangerously works...
    global.window = window;
  });
  it(`click event should be fired`, function() {
    const triggerElement = window.document.getElementsByClassName('trigger')[0];

   triggerElement.click();

   expect(triggerElement.classList.contains('test-class')).to.equal(true);

  });
});
```

So far my search has shown a few different options:

- [enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/) Tried this, it will require a react adapter to work. Seems to be an overkill since I want to test vanillaJS?
- [simulant](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/simulant) While implementing I don't get past an error: `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. Even when I implement something like [jsdom-global](https://github.com/rstacruz/jsdom-global) (which makes the window object available in Node env) Can this only be used in a browser environment?
- [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) This seems to be quite verbose.
- [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) This seems promising for the use-case. However is this compatible with JSDOM?

**What should I be using to simulate a click event for vanilla JS?**

---

update:

Setting JSDOM to dangerously works. However, comes as the name 'dangerously' suggests with a risk. [(source)](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#executing-scripts)

Just running your scripts in the node environment (and in the CI for that matter) doesn't seem desired.

Comment: It seems that in the industry, overkill or not, JSDOM goes hand-to-hand with Enzyme especially in the NodeJS environment.

Comment: @igreka You're right: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html. I missed that...

Comment: @igreka would you happen to have an example of an vanilla JS click element event with enzyme?

Comment: It seems that you cannot run it to test click events without react?

Comment: That sucks. I don't have any examples though. Sorry.